# List Items Not Showing When They Are All DIV Tags

Tags: html, css, razor, html-lists

I have a cshtml page that has a list of images in DIV tags. It looks like this:

```
        <div id="ActionButtonContainer" class="containerRight">
            <div id="ActionButtonSidebar" class="sidebarRight">
                <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                    <li title="Show More"><div class="icon lefticon" onclick="openNav()" /></li>
                    <li title="Edit"><div class="icon editicon" /></li>
                    <li title="Save"><div class="icon saveicon" /></li>
                    <li title="Cancel"><div class="icon cancelicon" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I run the above code, nothing shows up on the page. If change 1 of the elements to an image tag, all of a sudden all 4 items show up:

```
        <div id="ActionButtonContainer" class="containerRight">
            <div id="ActionButtonSidebar" class="sidebarRight">
                <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                    <li title="Show More"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="icon lefticon" onclick="openNav()" /></li>
                    <li title="Edit"><div class="icon editicon" /></li>
                    <li title="Save"><div class="icon saveicon" /></li>
                    <li title="Cancel"><div class="icon cancelicon" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The reason the src is that string, is that represents a blank 1kb image. If that's not there, Chrome will automatically put a border around the image for some stupid reason. I have tried src='', src='#', src='//:0', src='javascript:void(0)', they all end up showing a broken image on top of the image defined in the CSS class.

The reason I want the image source defined in the CSS file that when I change the src of the image tag to the actual image file, it refuses to size properly. I fought with it for an hour and I don't hate myself enough to continue down that road.

Any idea why none of the elements show when it's all DIV tags? Or how to remove the border around the image when no source is defined in Chrome in a more elegant less 'hacky' way?

Here's the CSS for reference:

```
.containerRight {
    clear: both;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: 90%;
}

.containerRight li {
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

.containerRight button {
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebarRight {
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 100px;
    left: 93%;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidebar2 */
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.editicon {
    background-image: url("../../../Images/edit.png");
}
```

Comment: Your html is invalid - you cannot self close a div tag - use a closing div tag

Comment: @Pete yes you are correct about the div tags, that happened by accident when I was switching between <img> and <div> tags in my troubleshooting. Closing the tags properly did not solve the problem though unfortunately.

Comment: your images are actually showing in the code above - if I replace your image source with an actual image it shows up - the only thing I can say about the code you show is that you push everything left 90% so it's going off the screen to the right.  If that's your problem,then instead of using left, use `right:0`;  Also your container only seems to be 80px wide and then you push your sidebar 90% left of that too

Comment: @Pete, you sir, are correct. That was the problem. It's weird to me that using an <img> would cause it to shift so much, but whatever. It works now with just <div>. Thanks!

Comment: no problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove border around the image: Should work with `outline: none`. Therefore it should be put to your `.icon` css class as far as I understood your issue.

```
  .icon {
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

However, you should generally try to provide a valid link with a img source that will be found and always include an `alt`-attribute on your image tag, so there will be an alternative text when the image couldn't be found.

I tried to reproduce your issue here. I can't see your local images of course, therefore it is all blank and I typed in ABC, so I don't really can reproduce your issue: https://codepen.io/alexiovay/pen/qBELZzy

Comment: In your example the outline still shows up if you remove the src string, add alt="", and add outline: none; to the CSS. You can see it in the output window below the ABC

Comment: I have found this is only an issue with Chrome. From what I've read Chrome does that to images when the src is not defined, and you can't CSS your way out of it. Not that I've been able to find anyway.

Comment: Do you expect the source to be found? Because you should provide a valid source, or better save the blank image locally.

Comment: The sources would be valid, if I chose to use them. Them problem is resizing <img> tags is such a nightmare. Pete answered my question regarding the <div> tags I want to use so I'm going to go that way. But thanks for your help!